# How do I render two scenes on top of eachother in THREEJS

Tags: threejs-editor

Please show me some code example on how to properly set the effect composer using threeJS to render two scenes on top of each other. I honestly  don't understand why the second one is always clearing the first. I am using autoclear = false in the renderer.

I tried this

```
    `this.composer = new EffectComposer( this.ref );
    const backgroundPass = new RenderPass( this.back, this.camera );
    backgroundPass.clear = false;
    backgroundPass.clearDepth = false;
    backgroundPass.clearAlpha = false;

    this.composer.addPass( backgroundPass );
    
    const mainPass = new RenderPass( this.scene, this.camera );
    mainPass.clear = false
    mainPass.clearDepth = false
    mainPass.clearAlpha = false
    this.composer.addPass( mainPass );`
```

Comment: Not sur but in the documentation it's say "RenderPass is normally placed at the beginning of the chain in order to provide the rendered scene" so I think the second take the order of the first, you maybe should use a custom pass for the second https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-use-post-processing

Comment: is it not possible to do a load operation? Render on top of another target?